# PE File Parsing c/c++

Tags: c++, c, portable-executable

I need to do a program in C/C++ in witch one i'll need to take each sction of a PE File, hash them and sign them, I made yet the hashing and signing functions but:
I don't know how to get each section of a PE File as a char* or byte*,
I don't know how to if i can use a simple fstream and search to a n byte,
and after that how to add a new section .sig to the PE File with my signature table.
Thanks for help

Comment: @ChrisJ.Kiick http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the documentation here:

[Microsoft PE and COFF Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx)

Sample code from CodeProject: [Parse a PE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36928/Parse-a-PE-EXE-DLL-OCX-Files-and-New-Dependency-Wa)

Comment: Do you have a sample code?

Comment: Sorry, what i need is may be an code example of using it on a fstream, on this page there is just a code of the struct of winnt.h.

Comment: I don't know how to use it, I mean how to open a fstream and from it return the number of section or any other thing