# Editing the IAT (redirecting to another DLL) at process startup

Tags: c, winapi

I have an application, X, that uses functions from the DLL file A and has it referenced in its IAT. I would like to programmatically (not manual patching) force X to load my replacement DLL, B, with the functionality emulated, in other words, alter the IAT so my file, B.dll, is loaded instead. To illustrate:

```
X's IAT: A.TestFunction
```

Before the process starts, I would like to change that to

```
B.TestFunction
```

I want to do this when the process starts: a launcher modifies the IAT of X.exe (again, not patching the HDD file; I mean a one-time change), then actually starts the process, so I need to do this programmatically, just patching the IAT is not an option.

IAT hooking is not exactly what I'm looking for in this case, as I don't want to override the procedures loaded by the Windows loader, instead I want it to load my DLL at startup. Of course, one could create a dummy A.dll with functions forwarded to B.dll, but I want to have as few files as possible, so I'm looking for a better solution.

The application isn't mine and I don't have access to the source code, so modifying it is out of question.

**The question:** What APIs should I use to create the loader mentioned above, capable of patching the .exe's IAT before starting it?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to edit the IAT before X is actually loaded, so you actually want to modify X's binary beforehand, not an runtime ?

Comment: Yes, this will eliminate the need for A.dll altogether, as the loader will never even try to load anything from it.

Comment: Can you simply replace the original DLL with a proxy?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I do not want to keep the name, hence the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized all I need is to call CreateProcess with the CREATE_SUSPENDED flag (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in my launcher app. I can then freely mess around with the IAT and resume the process once I'm done.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace one of the loaded DLLs with your own it's actually very easy.

You can get a list of the imports with LordPE (PE Editor -> Directoried -> Import Table (Not IAT!)), and in particular you will get the "Name RVA" for each DLL imported.

[image: screenshot of LordPE]

This is the address of where the name of that DLL is stored in your binary.
For example on my screenshot if you go look at RVA 0x1A46C you'll see the string "SHELL32.dll". Either edit the string in place with your favorite hex editor or add a new string somewhere else and change the "Name RVA" in LordPE to point to your new string.

Now if you want to do the same thing programatically, the method is the exact same, but you'll have to do LordPE's job. That is, parsing the PE header.
You can look at this question if you want more infos on how to parse it : [PE File Parsing c/c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007223/pe-file-parsing-c-c)

Comment: Yep, except I want to do it programmatically, in a launcher.

Comment: Then you'll just have to parse the PE header and you can go fix the Import directory in the exact same way. LordPE will give you the value of almost every field in every part of the PE headers and directories, if you need an example.

Comment: Yep, but another thing is, I don't want to permanently modify the .exe file on disk; I want to do it at startup, every single time, with the launcher modifying the file in the memory.

Comment: There's no easy way to do that. Once the Windows Loader has loaded the PE from disk, it's too late to change the imports, they have already been resolved. You should make a temporary copy of the file on disk, modify the copy on disk and delete it when you're done.
If you really don't want to touch the file on disk, then you can use MapViewOfFile and implement your own PE Loader or try to reverse engineer a kernel function that can start a process directly from memory, but good luck with that. I don't know if you're writing malware (are you?), but if it was that easy, everyone would do it.

Comment: No, I'm playing around with an old game, but I still want to be careful so as not to get any legal trouble from distributing copyrighted files (if I were to publish anything). At any rate, since your answer is the most complete and helpful, +1 and accepted :)

Comment: Simply replacing the game's `A` DLL with a replacement that maps everything to the `B` DLL is going to be a lot easier than patching the Imports table everytime the game is run.  Or simply rename the original `A` DLL to something else and then rename the `B` DLL to `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Your app cannot alter its own Imports table before it starts running.  You will have to either:

1. create a separate launcher app that patches the main app's Imports table before then starting the main app.
2. use your compiler's [delay-load feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) (if it has one).  Delay-loading uses a different PE table that gets processed at runtime by your compiler's RTL, rather than at startup by the OS.  Delay-loaded DLL functions are loaded on an as-needed basis at runtime when they are called by your code for the first time.  So you can use a delay-load hook to intercept the loading of `A` so you can load and return a handle to `B` instead.
3. do not statically link to your DLL functions to begin with.  Explicitly use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` in your code where needed (delay-loading uses these functions internally).

Comment: 1) Yep, that's what I want to do. I don't know how to accomplish it under Windows though, and that's what the question is about.
2) & 3) - as specified in the question, the application isn't mine, so I can't do that.

Comment: Your launcher app will have to open the main app's .exe file and manually alter the Imports table directly, replacing any references to `A` with `B`. There is no API that will do it for you. Read this MSDN article for more details: [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)